# Use of namespace in ROS plugins

Tags: plugins, namespaces, ros

I'm starting to work with ROS and plugins and I would like to understand one thing: What the use of different namespaces for the base class and the plugin class in ROS ?

I can understand the utility of namespace to differentiate similar nodes or Topics used by different nodes but I quite don't understand its use when we talk about plugins.

To be clear, why in the tutorial the base class use the namespace polygon_base and the plugins use the namespace polygon_plugin

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Initial disclaimer: Plugins are chiefly used by libraries who need the extended features Plugins provide. For the average ROS developer, there are usually better design choices.

The use of namespaces in ROS is to reduce confusion, especially with similarly and simultaneously operating things. For example, topic namespacing is (almost exclusively) used for running the same launch file multiple times, most commonly to launch/simulate multiple robots, or multiple sensors.

In the tutorial you mentioned (with badly formatted URL) (https://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib/Tutorials/Writing and Using a Simple Plugin), the only real use of namespaces are C++ namespaces. I think they used two different namespaces to disambiguate two similar kinds of code. The polygon_base code is not intended to be used as a plugin, it simply is a base. If it could be used as a plugin, it would be included in the polygon_plugins namespace.

In short, pick what is most clear and communicative as your naming schemes.